# Save entities in batch to Database

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.0

I am creating a web API that stores log messages in a database. The requirements specify that my API needs to be able to store 900 messages per second, in parallel. I have created the following simple repository method to insert entities:

```cs
public async Task<int> InsertListAsync(IEnumerable<LogMessage> logMessages)
{
    await _context.LogMessages.AddRangeAsync(logMessages);
    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This is my controller code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> LogMessage([FromBody] IEnumerable<LogMessageDTO> logMessageModels)
{
    try
    {
        var logMessages = logMessageModels.Select(x => LogMessageDTOMapper.Map(x));
        await _repo.InsertListAsync(logMessages);
        return new OkResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(1000,e,"Error while processing LogMessages");
        return BadRequest($"Error while processing LogMessages:{e.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

This test works fine for a relatively small amount of clients sending requests at the same time (max 90).
However, I have written the following integration test (the `GetStringContentForPostRequest` function basically creates an amount of randomly generated LogMessages, in this case, 1):

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test_MultipleRequests()
{
    // Arrange
    var client = _factory.CreateClient();
    //Act
    var responses = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++)
    {

        responses.Add(client.PostAsync("/logs", GetStringContentForPostRequest(1)));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(responses.ToArray());
    // Assert
    foreach (var item in responses)
    {
        item.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
    }
}
```

This test sends 900 requests at once, each containing one LogMessage. This test fails however, with error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
 ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 53300: sorry, too many clients already
```

One solution could be to higher the amount of allowed connections on my Postgres database server, but is there an easy way to first collect all received log messages over a period of time and save them to the database all at once?

Comment: Are you already using a connection pool?

Comment: @madflow I haven't tried that.

Comment: This sounds like an example where connection pooling could make your worries go away. But - I do not know if ef-core has this build in :S

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a ConcurrentQueue as a buffer for my LogMessages. Instead of directly saving them to the database in my controller, I added them to abuffer, that is injected as a singleton into my API.

```cs
public class Buffer: IBuffer
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<LogMessageDTO> _logMessageDTOs;
    public Buffer()
    {
        _logMessageDTOs = new ConcurrentQueue<LogMessageDTO>();
    }
    public ConcurrentQueue<LogMessageDTO> LogMessageDTOs()
    {
        return _logMessageDTOs;
    }

}
```

So my controller action now looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> LogMessage([FromBody] IEnumerable<LogMessageDTO> logMessageModels)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in logMessageModels)
            {
                _buffer.LogMessageDTOs().Enqueue(item);
            }
        });
        return new OkResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(1000, e, "Error while processing LogMessages");
        return BadRequest($"Error while processing LogMessages:{e.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

Which produces faster response times for the consumer calling this API.

This ConcurrentQueue is then emptied by a TimedHostService, which I read more about on this [Microsoft docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). What this timed host service essentially does, is emptying the ConcurrentQueue, and saving the items to the DB. This is the `DoWork` method of my TimedHostService:

```cs
private async void DoWork(object state)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Timed background service is working");
    var logMessageDTOs = _buffer.LogMessageDTOs();
    using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
    {
        var repository =
            scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<ILogMessageRepository>();
        var mappedLogMessages = new List<LogMessage>();
        while (logMessageDTOs.TryDequeue(out LogMessageDTO logMessageDTO))
        {
            mappedLogMessages.Add(LogMessageDTOMapper.Map(logMessageDTO,_logMessagePrefix));
        }
        await repository.InsertListAsync(mappedLogMessages);
    }
    _logger.LogInformation("Timed background service has stopped working");
}
```

This results in far fewer connections needed to the DB, as not every controller action instantiates a new connection to the database.